# Create empty csv file in R

Tags: r, csv

I have an R script that runs a set of functions on multiple datasets and creates a set of concentration-response models. What I would like to do is save out the model parameters and other results to a csv file.

My plan is to have the script create an empty csv file and then as the script progresses, results are appended to that csv file. Every time the script is run I would like the results to be overwritten.

I've tried to create an empty file using

```
system("copy /y NUL results.csv > NUL")
```

to create the file, but the file is not created. This command (i.e., `copy/y NUL results.csv > NUL`) works properly when run directly in the Windows terminal.

Am I missing something simple? System is Windows XP.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Is there anything wrong with `file.create()`, which is portable across operating systems?

```
file.create("my.csv")
# [1] TRUE
```

You can then append to the file, e.g. using the `append=TRUE` argument to `write.table()`, perhaps like this:

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:4, b=4:1)
write.table(df, file="my.csv", sep=",", row.names=FALSE, append=TRUE)
write.table(df, file="my.csv", sep=",", row.names=FALSE, 
            col.names=FALSE, append=TRUE)
```

**EDIT** If you will be doing a ton of writes to each file, it can save considerable time to open a connection to the file once, and only close it when you're done. If that is not the case, the approach above works just fine.

Comment: Also, try `apropos("file\\.")` to see some of the other file manipulation facilities available in base R.

Comment: It works but i'm receiving this: `In write.table(df, file = "my.csv", sep = ",", row.names = FALSE,  :
  appending column names to file`

Answer (score 5):

Because it is shell command you should use shell instead of system.

```
shell("copy /y NUL results.csv > NUL")
```

EDIT. More portable solution:

```
cat(NULL,file="results.csv")
```

Comment: That is not portable across operating system, thus taking away one of the hidden treasures of R.

Comment: Agreed, Wojciech. However, I will eventually need to run this (or similar) code on my other systems (Linux, Mac OS X). I agree that your answer is more specific to my question, but Josh's answer is more complete to the wider audience.

Answer (score 0):

how about just

```
echo > results.csv
```

Comment: I get similar results using `echo > results.csv`. I think the problem is with the system call rather than the actual command run, as any command to stdout (e.g., `system("echo Hello!")` produces no output.

Answer (score 0):

Use [truncate](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/seek.html).

```
f <- file("my.csv", open="w")
truncate(f)
```